# Find optimal training dataset after concept drift

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, supervised-learning, concept-drift

There are many strategies how to detect a concept drift or model drift, like when there was a major change in the underlying process so that the model becomes invalid. It can be an abrupt change or it could be a slowly changing process.

In both cases the model retraining, which can be triggered by the drift detection, should not be retrained on the entire available dataset, as it also contains the old data with a different distribution.

Are there any strategies how to select an optimal training set, so that the model works best with the more recent data and to automatically discard old data, that is not beneficial for current predictions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be phrased as *Bayesian detection* of moments of *structural change*. You do not choose a fixed data window $W$. Instead you assign weight $p(W)$ to window $W$. You can use the following model by Lai and Xing (2008).

On each day dependent variable $Y_t$ is normally distributed with mean $\beta_t^T X_t$ and variance $\sigma_t^2$. Here $\beta_t$ is a vector of coefficients and $X_t$ is a set of predictors. The vector of parameters $(\beta_t, \sigma_t^2)$ is stochastic and changes on any given day according to a Bernoulli process with probability $p$. When the change occurs, a new value of $(\beta_t, \sigma_t^2)$ is generated from a gamma-normal distribution, which is referred to as *hyperdistribution*.

Mathematically, the model can be summarized in the following fashion.

**Prior:**
$$
(\beta_t, \sigma_t^2) = (\beta_{t-1}, \sigma_{t-1}^2)
$$

or

$$
\tau_t \sim\rm{gamma}(g, \lambda),
$$
$$
\sigma_t^2 = \frac{1}{2\tau_t},
$$
$$
 \beta_t \sim \rm{N}\Bigl(z, \frac{V}{2\tau_t}\Bigr),
$$

where $z$, $V$, $g$ and $\lambda$ are the hyperparameters.

**Likelihood:**
$$
Y_t = \beta_t^T X_t + \varepsilon_t,
$$
$$
   \varepsilon_t \sim \rm{N}(0, \sigma_t^2).  
$$

**Posterior:**
$$
   \rm{E}[\beta_t | X_1, Y_1, ... , X_t, Y_t ] = \sum_{j=1,...,t} p_{jt} z_{jt},
$$
$$   
   \rm{E}[\sigma_t^2 | X_1, Y_1, ... , X_t, Y_t ] = \frac{\sum_{j=1,...,t} p_{jt} a_{jt}}{2(g_{jt} - 1)},
$$
where $p_{jt}$ are the weights. On pp 222 - 223, Lai and Xing list detailed formulas for $(p_{jt}, z_{jt}, a_{jt}, g_{jt})$ given the history of process $(Y_s, X_s)$ up to time $t$. It is important that the hyperdistribution can be chosen as reasonably “broad”. Does not need to be estimated from the data very accurately.

REFERENCE: Lai, T. L. & Xing, H. (2008) Statistical Models and Methods for Financial Markets. Springer.

UPDATE: Below I am showing the formulas for $(p_{jt}, z_{jt}, a_{jt}, g_{jt})$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the reference is not public, similar papers from that authors assume that the number of changes is known. Is there an example available to better understand the approach? I couldn't follow how to apply the mathematical formulation to receive the optimal training dataset.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the formulas for $(p_{jt}, z_{jt}, a_{jt}, g_{jt})$. Now you have the complete solution... Again, you do not choose a specific sample size $W$. With probability $p(W_1)$ you use the most recent data set of size $W_1$. With probability $p(W_2)$ you use the most recent data set of size $W_2$. If the weight for $W_1$ is $p(W_1) = 0.85$, then essentially you are using the sample which goes $W_1$ days back.

Comment: I still struggle with the daily (βt,σ2t): To get the daily normal distribution of Y: Do I just take daily mean and variance of the prediction of Y (e.g. based on a linear model - if so, which window do I use for training?) or is it independend from my model?

Comment: You use formulas $\rm{E}[\beta_t | X_1, Y_1, ... , X_t, Y_t ] = \sum_{j=1,...,t} p_{jt} z_{jt}$, $\rm{E}[\sigma_t^2 | X_1, Y_1, ... , X_t, Y_t ] = \frac{\sum_{j=1,...,t} p_{jt} a_{jt}}{2(g_{jt} - 1)}$ (in the middle of my write-up)... Again, you use *all* windows, with varying weights. Question "which window" is invalid here. *You do not know when exactly the latest structural changed occurred.*

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying. I like the approach to receive probabilities of different window sizes. Unfortunately I am not able to apply the mathematical formulation into an example. I can't derive from the paper the meanings of some variables. Do you think it's possible to explain it in simple words and an example?

Comment: A change in parameters $\beta_t$ (on some days) allows one to capture a change in the drift. The model also allows for a change in volatility $\sigma_t$ at the same time the drift changes. If you do not like that, you can just set the variance of $\text{gamma}(g,\lambda)$ to something small... On any given day $t$, you forecast that $Y_t$ is normally distributed with mean $\hat{\mu}_t = \hat{\beta_t}^T X_t$ and variance $\hat{\sigma_t}^2$, where $\hat{\beta_t} = \sum_{j=1,...,t} p_{jt} z_{jt}$ and $\hat{\sigma_t}^2 = \frac{\sum_{j=1,...,t} p_{jt} a_{jt}}{2(g_{jt} - 1)}$.

Comment: So for Y=[6,5,5,1,2,1,1] X1=[3,2,3,0,1,0,0] X2=[12,10,12,2,4,2,2] I would estimate for all 7 days my normal distributions using all possible windows. How would it look like for t=7 for example?

Comment: I told you how this would look. I gave you all the formulas. The next stage for you is to apply the formulas diligently: term by term, step by step. Doing that programmatically would probably be easiest.

Comment: I tried to apply them but I am not able to transfer the mathematical formulation to a practical example like above. I thought it would be easier to show on an example for interested people with less mathematical knowledge like me. Anyways, thx for your patience!